# Mathematica and Google Drive backup client

Tags: warning-messages, notebooks, interoperability, save

My *Mathematica* notebooks (as well as all other files I author in my research) are in a directory that is managed by the Google Drive client. This automatically backs up everything I create and I don't have any problems with any applications except *Mathematica*.

In *Mathematica*, every time I save a file I get the following popup:

> The notebook's file /Users/[user]/My Drive/notes/Books/[My Book]/Figures.nb has changed outside of the Wolfram System. The notebook has been renamed to Untitled-14. The Wolfram System has a complete record of changes made to the notebook, but might not be able to recover some of the unchanged cells. You can open the existing file again to reconcile any unsaved changes.

... and I'm forced to resave the notebook under the desired name.

Any suggestion on what's going on?

*Mathematica* 12.3.0.0 on MacOS Monterey

Comment: doesn't happen to me on mma 13, Monterey 12.1

Comment: Have you reported this to Wolfram Support to see if there is a workaround or explanation?

Comment: I understand that this comment is not directly related to the question, but I have been storing all of my notebooks and code files on OneDrive, a similar service, for years now without encountering any problem.

Comment: I've been using Google Drive for many years and this vaguely rings a bell. I think it is something to do with Google Drive making timed  backups of each file.

Is your directory synced for offline use, or are you streaming your files directly from Google Drive? Offline sync works fine for me on Windows via the Google Drive client, or Linux using InSync. But if you are streaming directly from Google Drive the file name or properties might be getting altered each time Google Drive does its new 'save point' backup, and Mathematica may be sophisticated enough to detect this and raise an error.

Comment: @RobF All my files are local and back up to Google Drive when they are changed. What I described happens after every save.

Comment: Exactly the same for me. Happens within seconds when a new file is saved, which suggests that the back-up process (which is triggered right away for a new file) changes the file in a way that Mathematica (but almost no other application) sees.

Answer (score 7):

I've been having the same problem. Disabling `"FileChangeProtection"` seems to solve it for me:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "FileChangeProtection" -> None]
```

(The default value is `"FileChangeProtection" -> Automatic`.)

See this link: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/245278